# glut - adding points to window

Tags: mouseevent, glut

I'm new in glut and I cannot solve this one.
I am drawing a points on a mouse click but always only last point is visible. How can I make older points not dissappear and on each click just add one more to them? (without saving all the points as variables or what, just make them not dissappear from window when drawing new one)
Thank you much.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "gl/glut.h"
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
} Point;

typedef struct {
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
} Color;

Point novy;
Color nova;

void Display(void){

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPointSize(8);

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glColor3f(nova.r,nova.g,nova.b);
    glVertex2f(novy.x,novy.y);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}


void onMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y){

    if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN){   
        novy.x = x / (double) 300 * (1 - (-1)) + (-1);
        novy.y = (1 - y / (double) 300) * (1 - (-1)) + (-1);
        glutPostRedisplay();
    } 
}

int main(void){

    cout << "suradnice \n";
    cin >> novy.x;
    cin >> novy.y;

    cout << "rgb farba \n";
    cin >> nova.r;
    cin >> nova.g;
    cin >> nova.b;

    glutCreateWindow("This is the window title");
    glutDisplayFunc(Display);
    glutMouseFunc(onMouse);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In opengl, display function is processed again and again. In your code in main function you didnt define a function like that :

```
glutIdleFunc(display);
```

So your code enter display function when you click your mouse. And of course your display function takes the coordinates of your mouse and draw this point.(Dont write this line in your code this is just an example how opengl works)

Display function draws each frame again and again independently.Dont expect to remember it your previous draws.If you want your other point coordinates to be in the screen, you should keep your previous click coordinates in an array and draw each one in your display function.

Comment: So in opengl it isn't possible to save previous state of the window and then just add new element into it?

Comment: You can search about **glFrameBuffers** to do it but it is little complicated since you said you are new in opengl.